# Forecasting datas, how to handle missing datas?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I'm having issues using ARIMA for forcasting a time series.
I have data with missing values and I need to have them to apply ARIMA on it, how can I do it ?

Here's an example of how the data looks:

```
City  utc_time Meteo(degrees)
A     12:00:00 21 
A     13:00:00 21
A     14:00:00 22
A     15:00:00 31 
A     16:00:00 
A     17:00:00 28
A     18:00:00 
A     19:00:00 
A     20:00:00
```

Comment: Are you asking "How do I change missing values to some value?"  Or are you asking "What is the best way to fill in missing values for my ARIMA calculation?"  These are very different questions.

Comment: It's more the second sentence that you proposed. I took the tutorial from this website: https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/02/time-series-forecasting-codes-python/ but when I use it for my datas, as my datas has missing values it gives me an error that the missing data can't be processed for testing the stationarity of the time series

Comment: . . In that case, I think the question is too broad.  People write PhD theses on imputing  missing values.  I would suggest that you use some different technique other than ARIMA that is more conducive to the data you actually have.

Comment: Do you know example of models that can be used other than ARIMA ?

Comment: Because maybe, there's confusions but to explain the whole thing. I need to take as training set the values until 18:00:00  and the testing set from that time to 20:00:00. As I have missing values I can't perform anything on it, so I have to handle these missing values.

Answer (score 1):

You may also consider `.interpolate()` as follows:

```
df["Meteo(degrees)"].interpolate(method="linear")
```

and pick the `method` that you prefer. Docs [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html)

Comment: Is there a way to make it more efficient since I can have for exemple other values as the speed of the wind etc.. ?

Comment: You can use `df[df.columns[2::]].interpolate(method="linear")` to apply the same interpolation algorithm to all the columns after the first two. If you want to use various algorithms just iterate through the different columns and interpolate each one.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
df["Meteo(degrees)"] = df["Meteo(degrees)"].fillna(df["Meteo(degrees)"].bfill())
```